# How to open a new react component at the end of a stepper?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

When I reach the end of my stepper component, how can I open a separate component that is decoupled from the stepper?

This is part of my react functional component which controls forward navigation. When I reach the 'Done' button, I want the component to open:

```
                    <ButtonContainer>
                        {activeStep !== 0 && (
                            <PrevButton onClick={handleBack}>Back</PrevButton>
                        )}
                        <NextButton
                            variant="contained"
                            color="primary"
                            onClick={handleNext}
                        >
                            {stepList && activeStep === stepList.length - 1
                                ? 'Done'
                                : 'Next'}
                        </NextButton>
                    </ButtonContainer>
```

Is this something I would do in my `handleNext` function or do I create a separate function for this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Either create a new function and use a ternary conditition in the `onClick` prop or add an `if` to handleNext. I guess it is cleaner to use the ternary.

Answer (score 0):

To open a decoupled component, you could use a [Portal](https://reactjs.org/docs/portals.html):

> Portals provide a first-class way to render children into a DOM node that exists outside the DOM hierarchy of the parent component.

What you would have to do is add another `<div id="my-comp"/>` somewhere next to your *root* div (`<div id="root" />`). Inside this `div`, the *Portal* will be rendered, instead of as normally as a descendant of the *root* `div`. The portal component would have to return something like this from it's `render()` function:

```
render() {  
 return ReactDOM.createPortal(  
   this.props.children,  
   myNode,  
 );  
}
```

The first argument (`this.props.children`) is the component, which can be an `element`, `string`, or `fragment`, and the second argument (`myNode`) is a DOM element.

You can then import the `Portal` component in your *react functional component* and place it somewhere there. But it won't be rendered as child of that component thanks to the portal.

Check out this [codepen](https://codepen.io/gaearon/pen/jGBWpE?editors=1010) for an example.

Regarding the done `button`. Either create a new function and use a ternary conditition in the `onClick` prop or add an if to `handleNext`.